# Avada demo doesn´t works fine on Last Works Builder Element

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a new web using Avada and I am finding with a problem... The link that must to show on a mouse over each of images that shows the Last Works element, doen´t appear.

For example if you see this page: http://theme-fusion.com/avada_demos/fashion/?page_id=15 and you move the mouse over the photos you will see two icons: the magnified glass, and the link.  OK!!!

Now, on my page, with the cafe demo, it doesn´t work. I try to install the fashion demo (the same demo that I posted on the link), to make a little test, I created some portfolios, then I created a page with one Last Works element, NO MORE... and it works. When I make the same with the cafe demo... it doesn´t work!!

Has anyone had the same problem? Any idea how to solve? Any general configuration (I think I see all the theme cofigurations)??

Answer (score 0):

OK!!!! I found it at end.
It is the "Image Rollover Icons" options, must to be set to Link+Zoom.
Sorry a lot!!